# Removing properties which are not owned or inherited

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is my code.

```
function Material() {
    this.id = null;
}

function Box() {
    // Inherit Material props
    Material.call(this)

    // Define own props
    this.width = null;
    this.height = null;
    this.weight = null;
}

var box = new Box();

// Setting values to Box props
box.id = 12;
box.width = 250;
box.height = 350;
box.weight = '10kg';

// Not its property
box.color = 'red';

// TODO: Passing box variable via function which will return new object of Box without color property

console.log(box);

// {
//     'id': 12,
//     'width': 250,
//     'height': 350,
//     'weight': '10kg',
// }
```

So basically at some point I want to get rid of color property that got set on box object (which is not the property of Box Class).

I don't want to individually delete such properties since there can be many. I have no way to find out which properties to delete. But I just know which properties to keep (Its own & inherited).

I am using lodash here. I tried `_.forIn` alongside `_.defaults` but of no help.

Thanks

Comment: Set it undefined maybe? Or delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [these](http://jsfiddle.net/u1fpmpba/):

```
var diff = _.difference(_.keys(box), _.keys(new Box()));
var clear = _.omit(box, diff);
console.log(clear);
```

`clear` - is a copy of `box` object with initial collection of properties

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy `Box` object, loop through your object's properties and check, whether or not dummy object contains it:

```
function Material() {
    this.id = null;
}

function Box() {
    // Inherit Material props
    Material.call(this)

    // Define own props
    this.width = null;
    this.height = null;
    this.weight = null;
}

function removeAdditionalProperties(obj) {
  var dummy = new Box();
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!dummy.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      delete obj[key]; // Or whatever you want to do with that prop
    }
  }
} 

var box = new Box();

// Setting values to Box props
box.id = 12;
box.width = 250;
box.height = 350;
box.weight = '10kg';

// Not its property
box.color = 'red';

removeAdditionalProperties(box);

console.log(box);
```